# How to route differently a request if param empty

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

On Symfony 4.3, I'm trying to route differently a request like below:

```
index:
  path: /{param}
  controller: App\Controller\MyController::doSomethiing
home:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\HomeController::home
```

But if I try to access `/`, the programm enter `MyController::doSomething` with an empty parameter.

I did what I want by checking if `param` is empty in the `MyController::doSomething` method but I don't think it is the proper way.

Is there a way to do this from the `routes.yaml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it finally. It's just about the order. The right configuration file is:

```
home:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\HomeController::home
index:
  path: /{param}
  controller: App\Controller\MyController::doSomething
```

Comment: You can also add a requirement on the param (https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements)

Comment: @ElliotBrl in this case would `\S+` be the right wildcard?

Comment: You can do something like this:  ```param: .{1,}```